# How can i declare a file name in c language?

Tags: c

I have this c module:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "targetver.h"

#include "libavutil\mathematics.h"
#include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"

FILE fileName;
```

I did File fileName;

This i have init function:

```
void init(const char *filename)
{
    fileName = filename;
    avcodec_register_all();
    printf("Encode video file %s\n", fileName);
```

So i did fileName = filename;
The reason i did is that i have another function i did called start():

```
void start()
{
    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }
//    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    errn = fopen_s(&f,fileName, "wb");

    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

And in start i had filename but it didn't find it so i wanted to use fileName instead.
But i'm getting now few errors:

On this line: fileName = filename; on the = symbol i'm getting red line error:

Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'FILE'

Then on this line:  errn = fopen_s(&f,fileName, "wb")
On the fileName i'm getting:

Error   2   error C2065: 'filename' : undeclared identifier

Same error number 2 on this line on the fileName: fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", fileName);

Then another error on the fileName = filename:

```
6   IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
        operand types are: FILE = const char *
```

Last error:     7   IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "FILE" to "const char *" exists

All i wanted to do is to declare global fileName variable to use it in all places.

Comment: Shouldn't the `FILE` variable be a pointer?

Comment: Almost certainly unrelated, but unescaped backslashes in string literals give me the willies.  Any reason for not using `/` rather than ` \ ` as a directory separator?  (Works in every desktop OS i'm aware of, including Windows.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FILE` is a type, used for representing an open file (it contains the file handle, position in file etc). You can't store a `char *` in a variable of type `FILE`, because they are different types. [Read about the FILE type here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output#Member_types).

What you want to do is store a file name. A file name is a string. Use a `const char *` instead. Your error message tells you this exactly: "can't convert a string into a FILE".

```
Error 1 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'FILE'
```

Reading these errors and trying to understand what they actually mean can help you solve problems like this. If the compiler complains about converting one type to another, it's a clear sign that you've got confused about the type of the value or the variable you're trying to assign it to.